# Visual Studio Code Suggestions Coming up to fast

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio Code from hammering me with suggestions as I'm typing? I find it really annoying.  I'd be OK if I stopped typing and the suggestion came up, but as I type, I keep seeing all kinds of suggestions like a flashing cursor.

Comment: Look in the Settings for `Hover: Delay`.

Comment: I set it to 2000 and I still get the problem behavior.  Here is a short demo of it.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/j0dl2ydobqqrh5g/problem-delay.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for

```
 "editor.quickSuggestionsDelay": 1000000,
```